# The Default Parameter Set isn't is running through the if Statement

Tags: powershell, parameters, default-parameters

When I run this function without specifying the Count Parameter, it asks for the Source, which is expected, then doesn't return the information that the Count switch should return, but if I specify the Count Switch it returns the information I requested.

```
function Get-EventCounts
{
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = "Count")]
param (
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "Count", Mandatory = $false)]
    [Switch]$Count,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "Message", Mandatory = $false)]
    [Switch]$Message,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "Message", Mandatory = $true)]
    [String]$EventID,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "Message", Mandatory = $true)]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "Count", Mandatory = $true)]
    [String]$Source,
    [String[]]$DaysBack = ("7", "30", "60")
)

If ($Message)
{
    foreach ($int in $DaysBack)
    {
        $EventList = Get-EventLog System -Source $Source -After (Get-Date).AddDays(- $int) | select EventID, EntryType, TimeGenerated, Message
        $MessageReturn = $EventList | Sort-Object -Property EventID | Where-Object -Property EventID -EQ $EventID
    }
    Return $MessageReturn.Message | Select-Object -Unique
}

If ($Count)
{
    foreach ($int in $DaysBack)
    {
        $EventList = Get-EventLog System -Source $Source -After (Get-Date).AddDays(- $int) | select EventID, EntryType, TimeGenerated, Message

        $UniqueID = $EventList.EventID | Sort | Get-Unique

        foreach ($Event in $UniqueID)
        {
            $Counting = $EventList | Where-Object -Property EventID -Like $Event

            $EventArray += @(
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    EventID = $Event; TimeFrame = $int; Rate = $Counting.Count; PossibleMessage = $($($eventlist | where-object { $_.EventID -eq $event }))[0].Message
                }
            )
        }
    }
    Return $EventArray
}
```

}

Comment: There is nothing in $Count in the scenario you describe. It has mandatory set to false, hence only $Source has content and the if statement never fires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to execute code based on the parameter set name rather than when switches are used. If that is the case, then you can change your `if` statement conditions.

```
function Get-EventCounts
{
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = "Count")]
param (
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "Count", Mandatory = $false)]
    [Switch]$Count,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "Message", Mandatory = $false)]
    [Switch]$Message,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "Message", Mandatory = $true)]
    [String]$EventID,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "Message", Mandatory = $true)]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "Count", Mandatory = $true)]
    [String]$Source,
    [String[]]$DaysBack = ("7", "30", "60")
)

If ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq "Message")
{
    foreach ($int in $DaysBack)
    {
        $EventList = Get-EventLog System -Source $Source -After (Get-Date).AddDays(- $int) | select EventID, EntryType, TimeGenerated, Message
        $MessageReturn = $EventList | Sort-Object -Property EventID | Where-Object -Property EventID -EQ $EventID
    }
    Return $MessageReturn.Message | Select-Object -Unique
}

If ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq "Count")
{
    foreach ($int in $DaysBack)
    {
        $EventList = Get-EventLog System -Source $Source -After (Get-Date).AddDays(- $int) | select EventID, EntryType, TimeGenerated, Message

        $UniqueID = $EventList.EventID | Sort | Get-Unique

        foreach ($Event in $UniqueID)
        {
            $Counting = $EventList | Where-Object -Property EventID -Like $Event

            $EventArray += @(
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    EventID = $Event; TimeFrame = $int; Rate = $Counting.Count; PossibleMessage = $($($eventlist | where-object { $_.EventID -eq $event }))[0].Message
                }
            )
        }
    }
    Return $EventArray
}
}
```

If you truly are trying to make decisions based off of the switches, then you would need to set a default value for `$Count` or add additional logic for when `$Count` is not present.